# RODBC sqlQuery: name with special character #

Tags: ms-access, rodbc

I am using RODBC to merge two tables in ACCESS. Here are my codes:

```
qry <- "SELECT * FROM 
        table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
        ON table1.Ref# = table2.Ref# "
result <- sqlQuery(connection, qry)
str(result)
```

Which returns the following error message:

```
 "42000 -3100 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression
```

I believe it's because I didn't use "table1.Ref# = table2.Ref#" correctly. With the special character, how can I modify this query? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the field names with special characters inside square brackets.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    table1 
        LEFT JOIN 
    table2
    ON 
    [table1].[Ref#] = [table2].[Ref#]
```

Also Access does not support OUTER Join, so simply try LEFT Join.

Comment: Thank you, Paul. I tried but now it says:     "07002 -3010 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1." ...

Comment: @Lily, is there a WHERE statement that requires a parameter? If so make sure it is passed to the Query.

Comment: No, I don't have WHERE statement. I am just trying to merge two tables by Ref#. Anyway, I got around the problem by creating temporary tables in R. Thanks for the help!